# When I click on the button it shows me an error

Tags: javascript, html

The error  ReferenceError: b is not defined     at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:32:30)

```js
 let s;
function b(){
      s = document.getElementById(k).innerHtml;
      animates();
}
```

```html
        <form class="form">
         <label>How much do you want to donate</label>
          <input type="number" id="k">
    <button id="l" onclick="b()">Cal</button>
    
        </form>
```

Comment: `innerHtml` doesn’t exist. Did you mean [`innerHTML`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)? Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. `b` clearly is out of scope as `onclick` expects your references to be in global scope.

Comment: `getElementById("k")` (you told JS to use the value of a non-existing variable `k`)

Comment: yeah but i will give it a value later in the form is there a way to do that

Comment: Also, note that `<input>`s do not have an `innerHTML`. You need `valueAsNumber` or `value` in this case. This is all explained in the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). One has to wonder, which outdated and incomplete tutorial you learned from…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to do a form for this, also inline events are not preferred use `eventListeners` in js.

**NOTE**: I've put input's value as result, but you didn't say what you exactly want, so *I think* this will work with you anyway

```js
document.getElementById('l').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =document.getElementById('k').value;
})
```

```html
<label>How much do you want to donate</label>
<input type="number" id="k">
<button id="l">Cal</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```